# Como repetir elemento en loop hasta que una condicion se cumpla?

Tags: python

Tengo dos listas y estoy creando una relacion entre ellas. Tal que casa elemento de la lista a va a ser comparado con los elementos de la lista b. Si a [i] > b [i] entonces se eliminara el elemento en b, y al mismo tiempo a[i] va a perder un entero (es decir, si a valia 5 y b 4, entonces 5 > 4, entonces se elimina el 4 de la lista b y el nuevo valor de a[i] que antes era 5, ahora es 5 - 1 = 4). Si a [i] <= b [i] entonces se elimina en elemento en la lista a y, b tambien pierde el valor de un entero.

Se considera a la lista "ganadora" la que no se acabe antes que la otra.

Por ejemplo:

```
a = [5, 6, 3, 6, 4]

b = [3, 7, 5]


5 vs 3 (Gana a) -> 5 - 1 = 4 (el valor ganador pierde el valor de 1)
4 vs 7 (Gana b) -> 7 - 1 = 6
6 vs 6 (Gana b) -> 6 - 1 = 5
3 vs 5 (Gana b) -> 5 - 1 = 4
6 vs 4 (Gana a) -> 6 - 1 = 5
5 vs 5 (Gana b) -> 5 - 1 = 4
4 vs 4 (Gana b) -> Gana b, ya que no quedan elementos en a
```

sin embargo no se como lograr hacer que el valor que gana se repita en el loop con su valor actualizado (es decir -1). Lo que me gustaría lograr es repetir el loop para el elemento de la lista ganadora con su valor actualizado.

Por ahora tengo este codigo, pero como dije no logro solucionar ese problema, mi codigo actual es este:
(la lista a es l, y la lista b es l2, tambien pongo un mecanismo para poder introducir las listas con inputs):

```
a = str(input())
l = []
i = 0
while a != "end":
    l.append(int(a))
    a = str(input())

a = str(input())
l2 = []
while a != "end":
    l2.append(int(a))
    a = str(input())

while len(l) != 0 and len(l2) != 0:
  for soldado in l:
    if i != 0:
      i = 0
      pass
    for enemigo in l2:
      z = soldado - enemigo
      if z > 0:
        l[l.index(soldado)] = soldado - 1
        soldado = soldado - 1
        l2.pop(l2.index(enemigo))

      if z <= 0:
        l2[l2.index(enemigo)] = enemigo -1
        l.pop(l.index(soldado))
        i += 1
        break
```

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

No uses un ciclo `for` cuando elimines o agregues elementos del iterable mientras iteras, invalidas el iterador. Además el `for` al iterar sobre el iterador generado te impide volver a iterar sobre el mismo item. En vez de eso, puedes usar un simple ciclo `while` con indizado y un condicional.

Tal como lo has planteado, si no he malinterpretado nada, no necesitas iterar sobre las listas realmente, en cada iteración eliminas un item de una lista y en la otra continuas con el mismo índice. En la práctica, siempre indizas sobre el primer elemento de ambas listas.

```
a = [5, 6, 3, 6, 4]
b = [3, 7, 5]

while a and b:
    a_item, b_item = a[0], b[0]
    print(f"{a_item} vs {b_item}", end=" ")
    if a_item > b_item:
        del b[0]
        a[0] -= 1
        print("(Gana A)")   
    else:
        del a[0]
        b[0] -= 1
        print("(Gana B)")

print("Gana A" if a else "Gana B")
```

> ```
> 5 vs 3 (Gana A)
> 4 vs 7 (Gana B)
> 6 vs 6 (Gana B)
> 3 vs 5 (Gana B)
> 6 vs 4 (Gana A)
> 5 vs 5 (Gana B)
> 4 vs 4 (Gana B)
> Gana B
> ```

Sin los prints intermedios puedes simplificar:

```
a = [5, 6, 3, 6, 4]
b = [3, 7, 5]

while a and b:
    if a[0] > b[0]:
        del b[0]
        a[0] -= 1
    else:
        del a[0]
        b[0] -= 1
print("Gana A" if a else "Gana B")
```